# How does this relation produce candidate keys?

Tags: database-normalization, functional-dependencies, candidate-key

Given relation

R(a,b,c)

and that there are **no** functional dependencies:

How are candidate keys computed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you determine functional dependencies and a primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27372640/how-do-you-determine-functional-dependencies-and-a-primary-key)

Comment: Your post is a duplicate many many times over. [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you mean there are no *non-trivial* functional dependencies (since dependencies like `a -> a` always hold).

Each relation is a set, so it must have at least a candidate key, that is a set of attributes that determines each attribute of the relation.

Consider an attribute like `a`, which is not present in any non-trivial functional dependency. In order to be determined by a candidate key, that candidate key *must* contains it.

So the rule is very simple: each attribute that is not present in *any* non-trivial functional dependency *must* be present in *every* candidate key.

In this case no attribute is present in any non-trivial functional dependency, so that the only possible candidate key is `abc`. In fact it determines all the attributes through the trivial dependency `abc -> abc`, and no other candidate key has this property.